# Does PlasticsCM apply a read-only tag on client files?

Tags: plasticscm, readonly-attribute

I'm currently using Perforce for source control, the files on my workstation in the source controlled workspace are tagged with read-only, Perforce uses this tag to help manage which file was checked-out. and Unreal Engine editor, takes advantage of that tag, and lets me know when certain file need to be checked out, I value this very much because sometimes you can be working on one asset, and affect many files without realizing it.

We also use Google drive with the Filestream client.  This mounts a g:/ drive on my workstation that I put all of my work project folders, not just code, but everything day to day work stuff.

This setup works great for everything, except... Google drive does not support "read-only" tags and makes using perforce more inconvenient, having to reconcile the project, or manually check files out( I am used to it happening automatically).

Now for my question about PlasticSCM... I might consider making the switch, but I've never used PlasticSCM, would someone be able to tell me if it uses the read-only file tag so that I could have my working source folder on the google drive mount g: ?

Many thanks and appreciation.

Comment: Have you considered making your Perforce workspace writeable (Allwrite)?

Comment: using the allwrite option, as far as I can tell, is the same as storing my workspace files on the cloud drive.  The end result is that I loose the feature that I value very much in Unreal Engine....oops, I forgot to mention my project is an UE4 project.  when  I modify a file in unreal, and try to save it, unreal would usually pop up a windows asking for a list of files to be checked out.  I do not get this behaviour when there is no read-only tag on the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use Plastic SCM (or any other SCM), I don't fully understand why you plan to use it at the same time with Google Drive.

You can use a Plastic workspace from where you can checkin your changes to a cloud repository. Then other members of your team can create a local workspace pointing to the same repo and this way, they can be up to date with your last changes in the project.

Anyway, **answering to your specific question:**

- Plastic SCM by default doesn't set local files are read-only in your workspace.
- You can still manually enable this workflow with the following preference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for input, it gave me the confidence to get the Plasticscm trial, and voila, putting the Workspace on the G: (google drive mount) does not break the functionality that I feel is important for me and my colleagues. when we modify an asset, whatever files affected as a result will be detected by unreal/plasticscm and up pops a window asking "do you want to checkout these files.  Perfect!!  Thank you so much.